# Boto3 client alternative for resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

What would be the client alternate for this?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('name')
```

I want to use client but that has a list_buckets function. Is there a way to pass a bucket name to client instead of getting the details from the result array??

Comment: What are you trying to do after specifying the bucket?

Comment: There's no direct client-level equivalent of the resource-level code you've written. The client interface doesn't create Python objects to represent AWS resources (like S3 buckets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the bucket names

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
buckets = s3.buckets.all()

for bucket in buckets:
    print(bucket.name)
```

I don't think you can only get the names.

But there is a tricky way to use the client

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.list_buckets()['Buckets']
```

where it gives the client responses.